# Changing URL for a link on iOS/ipad (in-app)

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, click

I'm editing a webview that is embedded in an ipad app. It contains various multimedia elements that I can not wrap in an  tag. So instead, I have an  element on the page and change the href dynamically depending on what the user is doing, and then force the click to occur.

This works actually fine, but the dynamic nature doesn't. Both work in Safari on ipad, but only the first one works in-app.

```
HTML:
<a class="mylink" href="http://www.google.com">Test Click</a>

javascript (on touchend):
$('.mylink')[0].click();
```

---

The above works. But this does not:

```
HTML:
<a class="mylink" href="http://www.google.com">Test Click</a>

javascript (on touchend):
var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/' + somethingDynamic;
$('.mylink').attr('href',url);
$('.mylink')[0].click();
```

If I put an alert after assigning the href attribute, I've confirmed that it has been properly changed. The click even just never happens in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.mylink')[0]`  will covert it into a **DOM object** and it does not have a **click()** method..

Instead try this

```
$('.mylink:eq(0)').click();  // This is a jQuery Object
```

Also assigning it a new href and **triggering the click event will not redirect** to the new link.. You would have to explicitly click the link..

Instead try redirecting it using **window.location**

```
window.location = url
```

Comment: OK, will give this a shot this morning.

My only doubt is based on the fact that I've already confirmed that the first block works totally fine, both in-app and in Safari iOS6. Its the second block that is giving me trouble, and even then, in-app only. Based on your reply, neither block should work, but they do.

The oddity is why it would fail *only* when I use jquery to change the href attribute before running the click() command.